# TFS 2010 custom build step

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

I am playing with TFS 2010, and am trying to setup a build process that will have some custom steps.

These include things like, stopping/starting IIS, search and replace files etc... across environments.

I have tried to look for examples online and have not found anything clear and meaningful on how to just run a script or something over the source files.   Looking at the default build process template (DefaultTemplate.xml) I cant make much sense of it.

How do I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For info on customising the TFS2010 workflow build templates have a look at Ewald Hoffman's series. Start with [Part 1](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119214553/http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx)).

I should also mention that since it looks like you're doing deployment then you may want to break deployment automation away from build automation.

Comment: Thanks for that Richard,  didn't know there was a separate solution for deploying with TFS.  I will look into it more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost exactly what I'd say for this question (Split build and deplyment stages, investigate TFSDeployer). One additional element is more generic - for deployment tasks you can't find an easy integrated tool you should create a custom deployment script. You can call any script by adding an "InvokeProcess" step in your Build workflow. TFSDeployer also has locations where you can insert custom PowerShell Scripts. (If you don't like PowerShell you can have PowerShell or "InvokeProcess" call a different script engine.)